# #import <ChatKit/ChatKit.h> file does not exist?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios4, xcode4

I have added the chat kit framework to my iOS app (i know it won't be accepted) and it says the file doesn't exist.  Any idea why?

Comment: If that's a private API, you'll have to generate its headers. You'll probably use `classdump` for that.

Comment: Are the ChatKit files in your search path?

Comment: nope. Do you know what the search path is for Xcode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigate to your project, then select your target. Click the Build Settings tab and use the search bar to look for the header search paths setting. Add the desired path and you should be set.